# slideToggle — accordion type FAQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I am trying to build a simple accordion style FAQ. If you click on a question, the answer is reveal.

I am having problems getting it to work, however. No errors in console...

Here is my JS code

```
$("#contact-fake > li > span").click(function(){

    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#contact-fake div').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

$('#contact-fake li div:eq(0)').show();
```

and my HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Who is it for?</span><div>Test</div></li>
    <li><span>Why do it?</span><div>Test</div></li>
    <li><span>How do we start?</span><div>Test</div></li>
    <li><span>When can we start?</span><div>Test</div></li>
    <li><span>How do we continue?</span><div>Test</div></li>
    <li><span>Next steps?</span><div>Test</div></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance (JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dXNyK/)
R

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).next().slideUp(300);` instead of  `$('#contact-fake div').slideUp(300);`

Also, as you're using the direct descendant selector (`>`) make sure the `ul` has the id `contact-fake`.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cvQYN/1/)

jQuery:

```
$("#contact-fake > li > span").click(function(){    
    if(!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
       $(this).next().slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});    
$('#contact-fake li div:eq(0)').show();
```

Comment: @rdck That's because you have just changed your markup in that jsfiddle to what your question shows. Here's your new version working - http://jsfiddle.net/dXNyK/2/.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [JQuery UI's accordion template](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)?